# Is it common to create a new case class for join tables?

Tags: scala, slick

I have 2 tables like:

```
users
id
name

lists
-id
-name

user_lists
id
list_id
user_id
```

So I currently have a query that returns:

```
def getUsersByList(int listId): Future[Seq[UserList]] = {
  db.run( userLists.filter(f => f.listId === listId) )
}
```

Now I need to join with the User table in order to get the User fields.

**What options do I have in what I return?  I guess I have to create a new case class and map to the fields somehow?**

Comment: You definitely can create a case class for that if you feel it's needed but you are not forced to. Have you seen [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39316792/how-to-join-two-tables-and-map-the-result-to-a-case-class-in-slick)? It's possibly exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your question (though maybe I am wrong) doesn't actually refer only to case class by rather to case class (aka `unpacked type`) and table mapping (aka `mixed type`). Also it is important to understand that `Slick` won't help you in any way with one-to-many / many-to-many relationships (it's not an ORM). Here a little bit more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42218139/2239369

Long story short - your join table is table as any other. The general straightforward answer is: **yes**. Just create one more `case class` and `table definition`.

You for sure need your join table definition (in short - this class that inherits from `Slick`s `Table` type - `mixed type`). Otherwise you wouldn't be able to generate appropriate query. You could probably go away from creating case class - but I am not sure if it is worth doing it - after all it's one additional line, right? ( `case class UserList(id: Id, listId: Id, userId: Id)` - or something close to this).

It's perhaps worth to mention that you can also go away from all of above by creating a view on DB level.

Comment: so essentially you have a case class for each table. The result of the query is a case class duple: Seq[(table1CaseClass, table2CaseClass)]. You map that sequence to construct your "uber" case class which represents the combined merged result.